# Geting Error For Generic Chained Comparator

Tags: java, generics, java-7, comparator

Before asking this question I want to say I am new in Java Generics. I have tried to implement Comparator chaining for a class so I have created this following class.

```
    static class ChainComparator implements Comparator<StudentDTO> {
    
    List<Comparator<StudentDTO>> chainComparators;

    @SafeVarargs
    public ChainComparator(Comparator<StudentDTO>... comparators) {
        chainComparators = Arrays.asList(comparators);
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(StudentDTO o1, StudentDTO o2) {
        for (Comparator<StudentDTO> comparator : chainComparators) {
            int result = comparator.compare(o1, o2);
            if (result != 0) {
                return result;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Here this class I have created for multiple comparator implementation for Student class. Now I am thinking this can be generic for all classes so I have tried with the following class.

```
public class ChainComparator implements Comparator<Class<?>>{
    List<Comparator<?>> chainComparators;

    @SafeVarargs
    public ChainComparator(Comparator<?>... comparators) {
        chainComparators = Arrays.asList(comparators);
    }
    @Override
    public int compare(Class<?> o1, Class<?> o2) {
        for (Comparator<?> comparator : chainComparators) {
            int result = comparator.compare(o1, o2);
            if (result != 0) {
                return result;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

But here I am getting the following compilation error

```
The method compare(capture#1-of ?, capture#1-of ?) in the type Comparator<capture#1-of ?> is not applicable for the arguments (Class<capture#2-of ?>, Class<capture#3-of ?>)
```

I am getting this above error on the below line

```
comparator.compare(o1, o2);
```

Can anyone please help me to understand why I am getting this error and how I can solve this error or my approach itself is wrong.

I can understand if I use any other library or Java8 I can achieve this very quickly with a decent code but actually I just curious and wanted to learn and understand Generic more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use wildcards here, because every wildcard is independent of the others.

`Comparator<?>` and `compare(Class<?> o1, Class<?> o2)` can be considered as meaning `Comparator<A>` and `compare(Class<B> o1, Class<C> o2)`, where `A`, `B`, and `C` can each be anything (wildcard), but you cannot of cause compare a `Class<B>` with a `Class<C>`.

What you need to do is declare a generic parameter.

```java
static class ChainComparator<T> implements Comparator<T> {
    
    List<Comparator<T>> chainComparators;

    @SafeVarargs
    public ChainComparator(Comparator<T>... comparators) {
        chainComparators = Arrays.asList(comparators);
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(T o1, T o2) {
        for (Comparator<T> comparator : chainComparators) {
            int result = comparator.compare(o1, o2);
            if (result != 0) {
                return result;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

You would then use it using the diamond operator:

```java
Comparator<Foo> chain = new ChainComparator<>(fooComparator1, fooComparator2);
```

Comment: Thanks for you help and good explanation. Actually I am thinking Comparator consume one class so I have to implement Comparator<Class<T>> on ChainComparator could you please tell me why we are passing only T not Class<T>  within comparator and what I have understand we need to mark as ChainComparator<T> because it contains a T type list am I correct?

Comment: @saba `T` *is* the class, e.g. `Foo`. If you wrote `Comparator<Class<T>>`, then the compare method would be `public int compare(Class<T> o1, Class<T> o2)`, but why would you want to compare the classes themselves, and not *instances* of the class?